# Mock Internal dependencies of unit while Unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm writing unit tests for a NestJs application (Node.js). Consider the classes below

```
class CatService {

  constructor(private walkService:WalkService){
    //....
  }

  public function doSomething(){
    this.walkService.walk();
    this.doThis();
    this.doThat();
  }

  public function doThis(){
    //....
  }

  private function doThat(){
    //....
  }

}
```

Now the question is if I want to write test for this `CatService` Class, Which dependencies would be need to mock? Also would we be testing the `doThat` method *keeping in mind it is private function*?

while testing `doSomething`

`WalkService` dependency would be mocked for sure.

but what about `doThis` & `doThat`?

*Summary*

Should we mock methods of the same class used by the method which is being tested?

If No then would it be unit testing? since a unit is a function here.

Comment: I don't think there's a right or wrong answer to this. Personally I like to test everything through the public interface and not test any private functions directly, in order to not tie the tests too closely to "implementation details" - I should be able to refactor the public function internals and private functions completely without breaking the tests (ideally). Since your public function calls another public function, I would assume your second public function has its own suite of tests, so I'd stub that one and just assert it's called. The private one I would allow it to be invoked.

Comment: the constructor of this class define its dependencies, thus you should mock `WalkService` as you've notice already. The private method will be tested as a side-effect of the public ones, I'd say.